# how to install wkhtmltopdf on wamp with windows 7 os

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Am working on this invoice page with textboxes where users enter numbers into them to get their orders. Now I use wamp on Windows 7 OS and I am trying to convert the page after the user have entered their figures to pdf and save it in a folder then output it in another window for viewing.

So far I have not been able to do much and it's driving me crazy for the past 2 weeks. Please, I need suggestions, really appreciate it.

Here is what I want and need to do:

1. Save the page as it is in html including the values in the text boxes.
2. Convert the saved page to pdf and store in a directory.
3. Email the pdf to user.

code so far

1. saving page html

   ```
   function printPDF() {
             var h = '<style></style>'+$('#article').html();
         var html = '<html><body><scr'+'ipt>';
         html += 'var form = document.createElement("form");';
         html += 'form.setAttribute("method","post");';
         html += 'form.setAttribute("action","/ajax/pdf/");';
         html += 'var h = document.createElement("input");';
         html += 'h.setAttribute("type","hidden");';
         html += 'h.setAttribute("name","html");';
         html += 'h.setAttribute("value","'+escape(h)+'");';
         html += 'form.appendChild(h);';
         html += 'document.body.appendChild(form);';
         html += 'form.submit();';
         html += '</sc'+'ript></body></html>';
         var w = window.open('','');
         w.document.write(html);
         w.document.close();
       }
   ```

but the problem is that it has to open a new window everytime and i dont want that i want it to be submitted at the background via ajax/jquery, secondly the created html document doesnt have the values in the textboxes they are all cleard.

1. convert page to pdf and store in directory

   ```
   $filepath = '/www/html/';
         $pdfpath = '/www/pdf/';
   $filename = date('YmdHisu');

    $html = urldecode($_POST['html']);

    file_put_contents($filepath.$filename.'.html',$html);

    $pdfcmd = 'wkhtmltopdf.sh '.$filepath.$filename.'.html '.$pdfpath.$filename.'.pdf 
   --disable-javascript';

        exec($pdfcmd);

       if ($fd = fopen($pdfpath.$filename.'.pdf','r')) {

        $fsize = filesize($pdfpath.$filename.'.pdf');

        header('Content-type: application/pdf');

       header('Content-length: '.$fsize);

        header('Cache-control: private');

        while(!feof($fd)) {

         $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);

        echo $buffer;

     }

         fclose($fd);

       }

      unlink($filepath.$filename.'.html');
   ```

have also used a wrapper i got for wkhtmltopdf but none seems to work

Comment: IS THERE REALLY A NEED FOR ALL THOSE CAPITAL LETTERS? Kinda feels like you are shouting at us :P

Comment: but @bol - those were the **only** capital letters in the whole post! ;)

Comment: @Lix: That's why the argument is `$title` not `$post` :)

Comment: am really very sorry guys : ( its just that the problem is driving me crazy.....really sorry once again.

Answer (score 0):

As for the title of the question: Download the latest windows installer from [The wkhtmltopdf download site](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list).

Please ask a lot more specific question. To me this looks like you are looking for a ready made solution to use rather than an answer to a specific question. Try going through the problems you are facing one step at a time and every time you encounter a problem, ask a specific question.

Start with something like: Can you install wkhtmltopdf? Can you call it from command line? Can you call it from PHP using static HTML files? etc. etc.